# Why bigquery can't handle a query processing 4TB data?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run this query

```
SELECT
  id AS id,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT users_ids) AS users_ids,
  MAX(date) AS date
FROM
  users,
  UNNEST(users_ids) AS users_ids
WHERE
  users_ids != " 1111"
  AND users_ids != " 2222"
GROUP BY
  id;
```

Where users table is splitted table with id column and user_ids (comma separated) column and date column
on a +4TB and it give me resources

> Resources exceeded during query execution: Your project or organization exceeded the maximum disk and memory limit available for shuffle operations.

.. any idea why?

```
id    userids   date
1     2,3,4     1-10-20
2     4,5,6     1-10-20   
1     7,8,4     2-10-20

so the final result I'm trying to reach

id    userids       date
1     2,3,4,7,8     2-10-20
2     4,5,6         1-10-20
```

Execution details:
[image]
[image]

Comment: are you under an organization? is there a slot limit applied by your manager?

Comment: @Pentium10 There is no slot limit in the organization

Comment: Can you post details on your query plan? See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation

Comment: @Martin Weitzmann Check the description now please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's constantly repartitioning - I would guess that you're trying to cramp too much stuff into the aggregation part. Just remove the aggregation part - I don't even think you have to cross join here.

Use a subquery instead of this cross join + aggregation combo.

Edit: just realized that you want to aggregate the arrays but with distinct values

```sql
WITH t AS (
  SELECT
    id AS id,
    ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT uids FROM UNNEST(user_ids) as uids WHERE
      uids != " 1111" AND uids != " 2222")) AS users_ids,
    MAX(date) OVER (partition by id) AS date
  FROM
    users
  GROUP BY id
)

SELECT 
  id, 
  ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM UNNEST(user_ids)) as user_ids
  ,date

FROM t
```

Just the draft <strike>I assume id is unique</strike> but it should be something along those lines? Grouping by arrays is not possible ...

`array_concat_agg()` has no `distinct` so it comes in a second step.

Comment: `I assume id is unique` - I think, if `id` were unique - you would not need `MAX(date) OVER (partition by id) AS date`  - so this assumption looks wrong to me. but overall - agree with direction you suggest to OP

Comment: Unfortunately this gave me the same table .. Please check the data in the table

Comment: Sorry the tables didn't display correctly .. please check it now

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the update but it still produces the same error ..

Comment: My guess it that there are a couple of id's who aggregate too many user_ids. Can you check the frequency distribution of your ids? There's a limit to what you can cramp into an array

Comment: so what should we do if so ?

Comment: Hello, @MartinWeitzmann I found an article about clustering as it optimises aggregation, so I clustered the table by the id and your solution has worked! but without the "over (partition by maid)" part .. Really thank you so much! I will try to get the count of ids now per userids :D